# In Mac Os X Mountain Lion how to switch keyboard layout using a shortcut so it's immediate?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a problem in that changing keyboard layout on Mac OS X Mountain Lion is not immediate: I change the keyboard (by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, that's what I have) then I continue typing but the keyboard has not changed yet, but only a second after. When I see that the characters are wrong, I change again thinking that I may have not changed the layout, but what I really do is I basically change back to my original keyboard layout.

This is very frustrating, are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Select the previous input source" (⌘␣ by default) seems to have that delay but "Select next input source in Input menu" (⌥⌘␣ by default) doesn't. ⌘␣ also just switches between the two previously used input sources.